# Как закрыть PopUp кликом на серую область?

Tags: javascript, css

У меня попап реализован на css.
И когда я произвожу событие клик, даже на самой форме она закрывается.
Я сделал пример моего попапа на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/brendan8c/pen/zYoQXzG)
Когда открывается мой попап в URL добавляется строчка http://site/**#modal**
Вот один из последних примеров JS который я написал, другие я не буду писать, они всё-равно не работают так как нужно.
Быть может есть решение этой проблемы и на CSS.. Подскажите пожалуста

```
let writeForm = document.getElementById("write");
// Закрытие формы на серую область
document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != writeForm) {
        window.location.replace("#");
    };
};
```

На всякий случай добавлю сюда реализацию PopUp на CSS

```js
// Этот JS работает не корректно!!!
let writeForm = document.getElementById("write");
// Закрытие формы на серую область
document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != writeForm) {
        window.location.replace("#");
    };
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal__window {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4em 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#modal:not(:target) {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.open {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 208px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #5435a7;
  border-radius: 100px;
  &_a {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #ffffff; 
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="open">
  <a class="open_a" href="#modal">Open Modal</a>
<div>
<div id="modal">
  <div id="write" class="modal__window">
      <a class="modal__close" href="#">X</a>
      <h2>Please to meet you!</h2>
      <p>Hello there, I am a nice Modal Window.</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И когда я произвожу событие клик, даже на самой форме она закрывается.

А где в коде проверка на "саму форму"?
Из-за этого и будет закрываться, потому что если в форме есть что-то, оно будет равно `true` при условии `e.target.id != writeForm`, потому что оно не унаследует `id="write"` от родителя.

Добавьте в условие проверку на то, является ли нажатый элемент потомком в нужном элементе: `!writeForm.contains(e.target)`

Пример:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let el = document.querySelector('#write');
  console.clear();
  if(e.target !== el && !el.contains(e.target)) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
  console.info(e.target !== el, !el.contains(e.target));
});
```

```css
.modal__window {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="write" class="modal__window">
  modal__window
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ это было немного сложно для меня, я ещё плох в JS.. Скажите я правильно понимаю данное условие? "e.target" это исходный элемент, на котором произошло событие. Если событие клика произошло не на форме "#write" или не на вложенности формы тогда true

Comment: Да, получается именно так, как вы описали)